# Installing SQL server 2005 reporting services on Windows 7

Tags: sql-server-2005, reportingservices-2005

I am trying to install Microsoft SQL server standard editions 2005 reporting services on Windows 7. But the option to install reporting services are disabled in the setup. The same setup works for XP. I think there is some issue with IIS version. Please provide me the solution.

Comment: What IIS versions are you running on the XP box and the Windows 7 box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Microsoft:

> Before you install SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services, you must enable Microsoft ASP.NET and Microsoft Internet Information Services (IIS). To enable ASP.NET and IIS, follow these steps:
>
> 1. In Control Panel, click Programs, and then double-click Programs and Features.
> 2. In the User Account Control dialog box, click Continue.
> 3. Click Turn Windows features on or off.
> 4. In the Windows Features dialog box, expand Internet Information Services, expand Web Management Tools, expand IIS 6 Management Compatibility, and then click to select the following check boxes:
>
>    - IIS 6 WMI Compatibility
>    - IIS Metabase and IIS 6 configuration compatibility
> 5. Expand World Wide Web Services, expand Application Development Features, and then click to select the following check boxes:
>
>    - ASP.NET
>    - ISAPI Extensions
>    - ISAPI Filters
> 6. Expand Common HTTP Features, and then click to select the following check boxes:
>
>    - Default Document
>    - Directory Browsing
>    - HTTP Errors
>    - HTTP Redirection
>    - Static Content
> 7. Expand Security, and then click to select the Windows Authentication check box.
>
> Note If you do not enable all these features, the Reporting Services option does not appear in the Feature Selection dialog box of the SQL Server Setup program.
>
> http://support.microsoft.com/kb/934164

Basically, make sure all of these are taken care of before you go to install Reporting Services or it will be disabled.  This will apply for Windows 7 and Windows XP.